# where does content://media/external/audio/albumart come from and is this the same across all devices?

Tags: java, android, albumart

I get album arts by getting the album ids from the **MediaStore** column ALBUM_ID and then load them in Glide like this.

This code works fine but i would like to know what the **hardcoded sArtworkUri** with value `content://media/external/audio/albumart` comes from?
Is this a reliable way of loading these album arts and is this value the same across all Android devices?

**Code**

```
Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumIds.get(position));

GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(albumArtUri)
        .error(myImageList[randomNumber])
        .dontAnimate()
        .override(250,250)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
        .into(holder.albumPageIv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if there is a more reliable way but looking around it seems google uses it in [Media Provider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/51cba5e1acf1c56be3dc6c7c46a73a5a0409b452/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java)

```
public class MediaProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final Uri MEDIA_URI = Uri.parse("content://media");
    private static final Uri ALBUMART_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
```

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Comment: Good catch. Edited the reply